# How can I merge Objects inside the array of objects depending on specific field?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array containing objects :

```
let Array1 =  

[
  {
    "nom": "TEST",
    "parent": "QB",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "60f04b190161e73c42a512df",
        "uid": "QB32N-20210715-20758",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "QB32N",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": null,
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "162367462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST",
    "parent": "QB",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "456d465d45d89a7da8954d564a",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "Lova",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
  }]
  },
    {
    "nom": "TEST2",
    "parent": "QX",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA74",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
  }]
  },
      {
    "nom": "TEST2",
    "parent": "QX",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA75",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN75",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
  }]
  },
 {
    "nom": "TEST3",
    "parent": "QC",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA76",
        "uid": "7a897897-789745456123-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN76",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST3",
          "parent": "QC"
        }
  }
    ]
  },

]
```

I want to merge products of objects depending on the field nom & parent, as soon as this equal to another object i want to merge it and add the product in the array so instead of having many redundant objects with the same nom & parent and other fields if the nom and parents are the same on many objects merge them and add merge the array products too.
so it will look like something like this:

```
let final = [
  {
    "nom": "TEST",
    "parent": "QB",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "60f04b190161e73c42a512df",
        "uid": "QB32N-20210715-20758",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "QB32N",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": null,
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "162367462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Red",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
      },
            {
        "Id": "456d465d45d89a7da8954d564a",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "Lova",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "700X700 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
  }
    ]
  },
  },
    {
    "nom": "TEST2",
    "parent": "QX",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA74",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
  },
        {
        "Id": "ELA75",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN75",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
  }
  },
 {
    "nom": "TEST3",
    "parent": "QC",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA76",
        "uid": "7a897897-789745456123-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN76",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST3",
          "parent": "QC"
        }
  }
  },

]
```

Comment: Please post your attempted code.

Comment: @Nitheesh Sincerely didn't know where to start, since hours I'm watching the code and I'm lost

Answer (score 3):

Just do a reduce operation on your original array and see if the object with same `nom` property already exists. If so, check if the current item in the array has the same parent. If so, just add your `cur.products` to your already existing element and then return the accumulated result from the reduce.

```
const result = Array1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const doesExist = acc.find(a => a.nom === cur.nom);
  if(doesExist) {
    const doesParentExist = acc.find(a => a.parent === cur.parent)
    if(doesParentExist) {
      doesExist.products = [...doesExist.products, ...cur.products]
    } 
  } else {
    acc.push(cur);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this buy using normal loop implemntation.

```js
let Array1 = [
  {
    "nom": "TEST",
    "parent": "QB",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "60f04b190161e73c42a512df",
        "uid": "QB32N-20210715-20758",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "QB32N",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": null,
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "162367462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST",
    "parent": "QB",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "456d465d45d89a7da8954d564a",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "Lova",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST2",
    "parent": "QX",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA74",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST2",
    "parent": "QX",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA75",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN75",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST3",
    "parent": "QC",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA76",
        "uid": "7a897897-789745456123-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN76",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST3",
          "parent": "QC"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
]
const output = [];
let arr2 = Array1.forEach((node) => {
  const findNode = output.find((item) => item.nom === node.nom && item.parent === node.parent);
  if (findNode) {
    findNode.products = findNode.products.concat(node.products);
  } else {
    output.push(node);
  }
})
console.log(output);
```

**Edit**
`Array.reduce` implementation.

```js
let Array1 = [
  {
    "nom": "TEST",
    "parent": "QB",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "60f04b190161e73c42a512df",
        "uid": "QB32N-20210715-20758",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "QB32N",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": null,
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "162367462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Blue",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST",
    "parent": "QB",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "456d465d45d89a7da8954d564a",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "Lova",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST",
          "parent": "QB"
        }
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST2",
    "parent": "QX",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA74",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN74",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST2",
    "parent": "QX",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA75",
        "uid": "7a897897-20210715-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN75",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST2",
          "parent": "QX"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "nom": "TEST3",
    "parent": "QC",
    "products": [
      {
        "Id": "ELA76",
        "uid": "7a897897-789745456123-20756",
        "type": "fabricant",
        "statut": "publié",
        "app_ref": "RN76",
        "version_application": "1.1.0",
        "creation_date": "2021-07-15T14:42:41.465Z",
        "tit": "RESTA",
        "ref": "462378462",
        "description": "300x300 - 20 - Cross Black",
        "famille": {
          "nom": "TEST3",
          "parent": "QC"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
]
let arr2 = Array1.reduce((acc, node) => {
  const findNode = acc.find((item) => item.nom === node.nom && item.parent === node.parent);
  if (findNode) {
    findNode.products = findNode.products.concat(node.products);
  } else {
    acc.push(node);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(arr2);
```